# Java - weird ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I loop through a copy of a set of objects, but it still gives me an error starting at this method:

```
private static Set<Updated> updates = new HashSet<>();
public static Set<GameObject> getGameObjects() {
    Set<GameObject> objs = new HashSet<>();
    for (Updated up : new HashSet<Updated>(updates)) {
        if (up instanceof GameObject)
            objs.add((GameObject) up);
    }
    return objs;
}
```

(Where the for loop is).
This only happens when there are quite a few GameObjects, and never occurs when there's only a few (like 7). Thank you!

Comment: Where is the 'updates' value coming from? The only place in this code that can cause a ConcurrentModificationException is the new HashSet creation; the CME will happen if 'updates' is modified from another thread.

Comment: GameObjects implement updated and are added to the set on creation.

Comment: Is there another thread that can modify this set?

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: [You asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368454/java-set-gets-full), and the answer is the same. `new HashSet<Updated>(updates)` will iterate `updates`, which will throw the CME if you have another thread concurrently modifying it. Simple as that. In any case, creating a copy of that set to iterate from is wasteful and not useful.

Comment: More objects in the map mean more time to iterate means more chances for CMEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that somebody in another thread changes the `updates` set *while it is being copied* in `new HashSet<Updated>(updates)`.

You cannot do this without synchronization. Or use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashSet`

Comment: Also, note that for such a simple loop, you don't need to make a copy of updates. It just means you're iterating twice. You could make a copy if you needed a snapshot of the values for use over a longer period.

Comment: This is not true. You certainly need a copy unless you are either using `ConcurrentHashMap` or willing to synchronize the entire loop.

Comment: Synchronization worked, thank you.

Comment: @Dima, if you make a copy, that is iterating and adding to another collection. That's what the loop is doing except for a very simple and quick condition. Therefore, making a copy in this situation does not help.

Comment: @user12722 yes, like I said, either make a copy or synchronize the entire loop. `instanceof` isn't actually "very quick", but you do have a point, if this is all it does, copying would probably not win you very much.